# Mule 3.6 and Server Sent Events

Tags: rest, mule, jersey-2.0, server-sent-events

I am trying to add Server Sent Events to a REST component of mule 3.6 ESB flow. I am having trouble getting the data back to the browser. I do connect to the java method but after the EventSource is sent back an error occurs in the browser. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8082" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>

<flow name="RestService" >
<http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/*" doc:name="HTTP">
<http:response-builder>
<http:header headerName="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
<http:header headerName="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST"/>
</http:response-builder>
</http:listener>
<jersey:resources doc:name="REST">
<component>
<spring-object bean="RestService"/>
</component>
</jersey:resources>
</flow>
```

Java code using the Example on Jersey 2 SSE

```
@GET
@Path("/notifications")
@Produces(SseFeature.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS)
public EventOutput getNotificationEvents() {
final EventOutput eventOutput = new EventOutput();

         new Thread(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
            try {
                 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                      // ... code that waits 1 second
                      final OutboundEvent.Builder eventBuilder
                             = new OutboundEvent.Builder();
                      eventBuilder.name("message-to-client");
                      eventBuilder.data(String.class,
                      "Hello world " + i + "!");
                      final OutboundEvent event = eventBuilder.build();
                      eventOutput.write(event);
                  }
             } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(
                          "Error when writing the event.", e);
             } finally {
                  try {
                        eventOutput.close();
                  } catch (IOException ioClose) {
                      throw new RuntimeException(
                       "Error when closing the event output.", ioClose);
                  }
             }
          }
       }).start();

      return eventOutput;
 }
```

Javascript Connection code

```
var notifications= new EventSource("http://localhost:8082/notifications");

notifications.onopen = function (e) {
      console.log("Waiting For Message..");
};
notifications.onerror = function (e) {
      console.log("Error");
      console.log(e);
};

notifications.onmessage=function (e) {
       console.log(e);
};
```

Javascript console logs the onopen Waiting For Message.. then Error and the e event is the following. 
bubbles: false
cancelBubble: false
cancelable: false
currentTarget: EventSource
defaultPrevented: false
eventPhase: 0
path: Array[0]
returnValue: true
srcElement: EventSource
target: EventSource
timeStamp: 1433120172045
type: "error"

Comment: What is the error you get in the browser?

Comment: I added the javascript console above. Not much there besides just error.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this problem and if so how did you get it to work?